# cannot create javaDB in Netbeans IDE 8.2

Tags: database, derby, netbeans-8, javadb

Im trying to to create a java DB on netbeans IDE 8.2 but when I press right click to create the DB the option "create database" is off I cant use it and also everything in that list is not available nut the "properties" option.

what can I do to solve it ?

Im using windows 10

Comment: Update your question with two screen shots: [1] The context menu showing that all menu entries except "Properties" are disabled. [2] The "_Java DB Properties_" window that is displayed when you select "Properties".

Answer (score 1):

Possibly (I am guessing) you asked this question because you were reading an old tutorial which was written back when JavaDB was bundled as part of the JDK.

That bundling practice ended several years ago, and you must now [download Apache Derby from the Apache website](http://db.apache.org/derby/derby_downloads.html) and place the Derby jar files into a directory which is in your CLASSPATH.

When you download Derby, make sure that you choose the correct version for your Java version (if you are using Java 8, use Derby 10.14; if you are using Java 9 or greater, use Derby 10.15)